# run a command as user at boot time Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: boot, server, startup, users

I want to run a command at boot time that basically looks like this:

python /home/me/.hidden/commnd.py

Also, this needs to run as me, not root.

I know it can be done, but my google-fu is weak today.

BTW, this is a headless server, so starting at login isn't a solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the @reboot cron target.

Edit your user account crontab by using the crontab command:

```
$ crontab -e
```

Then instead of minute hour day month day of week, simply put @reboot

```
@reboot python /home/me/.hidden/command.py
```

For more info on @reboot and other cron special strings, read the crontab 5 manpage.

```
$ man 5 crontab
```

Comment: This worked for me.

As a note:  the python script I was using didn't like to be called the way I had it listed above, so I created a simple script that cd'd into the directory then called the python script.

Comment: You may also put more than one shell command as the cron job. @reboot cd /home/me/.hidden; python command.py